# ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.AA"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am new to PL/SQL
I was trying to save the deleted record into a temporary table. For that i made a trigger as follows :

```
create or replace trigger aa
before delete on master_table
declare
v_id number(2);
begin
select id into v_id from master_table;
insert into temp_table values(v_id);
end;
/
```

But when I try to delete a record from master_table , these exceptions are thrown :

```
ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows
ORA-06512: at "SYSTEM.AA", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SYSTEM.AA'
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the trigger to execute for each row and just use the `:old.id` to insert value into the temp table.

```
create or replace trigger aa
before delete on master_table
for each row
begin
    insert into temp_table values(:old.id);
end;
/
```